# How to get images from another server to my Express server and write to disk

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I need to get some images from another server to my server. I used superagent to send the GET request. I got the response but how can I use fs.createWriteStream to write the files to disk? And I want to watch the `finish` event.

I am using Express 4 and Node.js 5.3.0

```
function getPhotos(array) {
    array.forEach(item => {
        request // superagent
            .get(url)
            .query({media_id: item})
            .end((err, res) => {
                console.log(res.status);
                console.log(res.body);
            })
    })
}
```

the `res.body` is Buffer:

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 00 58 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 02 01 12 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 01 ... >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superagent supports [streams](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#piping-data), which means that you can stream the response of a request directly to a file (without the need to read the response entirely into memory first).

For instance, here's an (untested) example of your function that will call a provided callback once all files have been downloaded (by watching for the `finish` event for each file, counting the number of files that have been written, and comparing that to the total number of files in the array):

```
function getPhotos(array, callback) {
  var numFiles    = array.length;
  var numFinished = 0;

  array.forEach(item => {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(pathname, title)).on('finish', () => {
      if (++numFinished === numFiles) {
        return callback();
      }
    });
    request.get(url).query({media_id: item}).pipe(file);
  })
}
```

Some notes about this example

- the code does no error checking whatsoever;
- all files are downloaded concurrently which, depending on the size of the array, may pose issues; if that's not what you want, you could for example use [`async.eachLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) to limit the number of concurrent download 'tasks'.

Comment: @BrickYang in that case, you probably can't use streaming and have to read each response into memory first (much like your own answer). The `finish` event handling would still be usable, though.

Comment: Sorry, I missed somethin. The `title` in `fs.createWriteStream(path.join(pathname, title))` depends on the response value of superagent request, so I think I have to put the `pipe` inner the `end` method of `request`. And I found the streaming doesn't work just like what you said. :)

Comment: As you mentioned the error checking, can I use `try-catch` for the `writeStream.write()` method?

Comment: @BrickYang no, you need to handle the [`error`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error_1) event for that.

Answer (score 2):

After searching in document, I found the `writable.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])` method to handle this:

```
function getPhotos(array) {
    array.forEach(item => {
        request // superagent
            .get(url)
            .query({media_id: item})
            .end((err, res) => {
                let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(pathname, title));
                writeStream.write(res.body);
            })
    })
}
```

Done! It works great.

Comment: @robertklep ha! Edited. Thanks

Comment: Streaming the response (documented [here](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#piping-data) and also mentioned in Mohammed's answer) seems more preferable though, as it doesn't require the entire response to be loaded into memory first.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. This is what I wanted. Could you post an answer about this? I hope you could show some code including how to use the `finish` event? I will accept your answer.

Comment: The `finish` event isn't strictly necessary to watch, unless you have some specific requirements (for instance, wait for all photo's to have downloaded before continuing), which you should probably add to your question :-)